# AWS EMR: Is the "mapred.child.java.opts" option set per slot or per node?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

I was wondering if you set the `mapred.child.java.opts` option, does it set the amount of memory per worker node or per map/reduce slot?

For example `mapred.child.java.opts=Xmx2000m`, is that approximately 2 GB per node or slot?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general `mapred.child.java.opts` could be set for either per Node or per Job.

So assuming you have mapper's (`mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum`) + reducer's (`mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum`) running concurrently on a node are 12 then `mapred.child.java.opts` determines how much RAM is used by that node for child process.

Ex:

```
mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum = 10
mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum = 2
mapred.child.java.opts = -Xmx256m
total ram used by child processes = (10 + 2) * 256m =~ 3GB
```